# How to configure sshd_config to not accept dsa keys which are configured in publickey authentication?

Tags: ssh, sshd, openssh

I have publickey authentication configured for a specific client. The client is using dsa key of 1024 bit keysize.

I would like to configure the `sshd_config` in server side to not allow keys of dsa algorithm or 1024 keysize. Please let me know how I can configure `sshd_config` for this purpose.

Comment: You can find useful this http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29262/disabling-authentication-via-dsa-keys-in-openssh

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpneSSH version older than 7.0, then it is not possible.

If you are using newer version, the DSA keys are already disabled by default, though, it is disabled using the `HostKeyAlgorithms` option.

Comment: That did work.. One more question - when I do the earlier step it just rejects the connection altogether.. However if I want the authentication mechanism to fallback to password based, any way that can be achieved?

Comment: It think that is the default behavior to fallback to password authentication. Specifying the `HostKeyAlgorithms` does not prevent the connection altogether.